# How do I preserve special characters when writing XML with XDocument.Save()?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My source XML has the copyright character in it as `&#x00A9;`. When writing the XML with this code:

```
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
segmentDoc.Save(stringWriter);
Console.WriteLine(stringWriter.ToString());
```

it is rendering that copyright character as a little "c" with a circle around it. I'd like to preserve the original code so it gets spit back out as `&#x00A9;`. How can I do this?

Update: I also noticed that the source declaration looks like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` but my saved output looks like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`. Can I indicate that I want the output to still be utf-8? Would that fix it?

Update2: Also, `&#x00A0;` is getting output as `ÿ`. I definitely don't want that happening!

Update3: `&#x00A7;` is becoming a little box and that is wrong, too. It should be `§`

Comment: Your Update3 is buggy, U+00B6 is indeed ¶, § is U+00A7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect you won't be able to do this. Fundamentally, the copyright sign *is* `&#x00A9;` - they're different representations of the same thing, and I expect that the in-memory representation normalizes this.

What are you doing with the XML afterwards? Any sane application processing the resulting XML should be fine with it.

You *may* be able to persuade it to use the entity reference if you explicitly encode it with ASCII... but I'm not sure.

EDIT: You can definitely make it use a different encoding. You just need a `StringWriter` which reports that its "native" encoding is UTF-8. Here's a simple class you can use for that:

```
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
         get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

You could try changing it to use `Encoding.ASCII` as well and see what that does to the copyright sign...

Comment: I'm writing a tool that runs through an xml file and adds attributes that, according to a set of business rules that I have, are missing or invalid. Then, I want to spit the new xml back out. I do not have control over the system that ultimately reads the xml, so I wanted my own footprint to be the absolute minimum. I do not know if this other system is sane. I want to assume that it isn't.

Comment: @Chris: Edited due to the update. I wouldn't immediately assume that the reading system is badly written unless you have reason to. Can you not try the existing output first? It really should be equivalent.

Comment: Your Utf8StringWriter fixed the declaration output. Thank you! I am still trying to find a way to preserve the special characters, though. I did 2 more updates showing some others that seem really wrong, whereas the copyright symbol seems like it could be right.

Comment: I tried ASCII and every other encoding I could think of and still had no luck.

Comment: @Chris: I suspect the problem you're seeing in terms of other characters is that you're opening the file with a text editor which is assuming a different character encoding. What happens if you open it in a genuine XML editor?

Comment: Good idea. If I open the output xml in XMLSpy, it pops up a dialog that says "Your file contains 1 character(s) that should not be present in a file using the Unicode UTF-8 encoding... The offending characters are `ÿ (0xFF)`. It is referring to what gets swapped in for that `&#x00A0;`

Comment: @Chris: Hmm. What does that bit of the file look like in binary, out of interest?

Comment: I used the class you specified to get the declaration to be accurate. Then I did a crazy hack to preserve all special characters, using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem when saving some lithuanian characters in this way. i found a way to cheat around this by replacing `&` with `&amp;` (`&amp;#x00A9;` to write `&#x00A9;` and so on) it looks strange but it worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to diffent document encoding, check out:
http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CharEncoding.html

Answer (score 0):

It appears that UTF8 won't solve the problem. The following has the same symptoms as your code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(ms, new UTF8Encoding());
segmentDoc.Save(writer);
ms.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
var reader = new StreamReader(ms);
var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

I tried the same approach with ASCII, but wound up with `?` instead of ©.

I think using a string replace after converting the XML to a string is your best bet to get the effect you want. Of course, that could be cumbersome if you are interested in more than just the @copy; symbol.

```
result = result.Replace("©", "\u0026#x00A9;");
```

Comment: There are bunches of other ones, `&#x00B6;` and `&#x00A0;` to name 2 more.