# xml entity missing while loading document in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, xml

Hi i have a xml file with entities,
below is a piece of my xml code

```
<line>Intellectual life &#x2013; 1268&#x2013;1559. I. Title.</line>
<line>DG533.R84 2015</line>
<line>945&#x2032;.05&#x2013;dc23 2014019659</line>
```

when i load the above xml in c#, entities are missing and substituted with some other values,
may i know what is the reason

below is modified xml using c#

```
<line>Intellectual life – 1268–1559. I. Title.</line>
<line>DG533.R84 2015</line>
<line>945′.05–dc23 2014019659</line>
```

i want the modified xml as same as source xml

here is my c# code to do above process

```
using System.Xml;

XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("sample.xml");
doc.Save("sample.xml");
```

Thanks 
  Appu

Comment: What do you mean with 'an entity' ?

Comment: Include first lines of the XML files. You seem to be asking about Encoding issues.

Comment: Hi henk holterman this is my first line of xml file <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//CBML//DTD Book Publishing DTD V4.12/EN" "http://dtd.cambridge.org/schemas/2013/10/CBML.dtd">
<book isbn="9780521895200" xmlns="http://dtd.cambridge.org/2007/CBML">   when i loaded in c# it changes to <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<book isbn="9780521895200" xmlns="http://dtd.cambridge.org/2007/CBML">                                               DOCTYPE disappeared...

Comment: Add it well-formatted to the question. Xml in comments is not readable.

Answer (score 2):

[How do I preserve special characters when writing XML with XDocument.Save()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512825/how-do-i-preserve-special-characters-when-writing-xml-with-xdocument-save)

According to @JonSkeet's answer in the above link, they (the encoded entity and it's corresponding character getting saved) are just different representation of the same thing. This translation shouldn't cause you any trouble because *normally* the receiving party that process the XML further will recognize either representation as the same thing.

[XDocument.Save() removes my &#xA; entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811873/xdocument-save-removes-my-xa-entities)

If you really need to preserve the entities, there is also an attempt to do so by inheriting `XmlTextWriter` class and overriding it's `WriteString()` method to be manually replacing each special character with the corresponding entity. See the 2nd link above for example implementation. Anyway this approach is going to be cumbersome if you have many different entities to preserve.